# PHP - Recursive - Open URL Using Variable Created From Sub Directory Names

Tags: php, url, recursion, directory, subdirectory

I'm trying to write some PHP that runs through a folder grabbing each sub directory name and assigning it to a variable.  Then, open a URL with that variable.

For example, D:Folder contains a number of sub folders named 1-??.

The PHP would first open www.url.com/run_batch.php?q=1 and sleep for 30 seconds, then www.url.com/run_batch.php?q=2, etc... for each sub directory in the main directory.

I'm currently in the process of trying to write this. I don't have much code yet, but thought one of you geniuses could help me speed up this process.

**UPDATED**

Ok, here is what I have so far, it runs without any errors, but it appears to be running all of them at once without sleeping?  Not sure, the page just stays busy.

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('D:\HTTP\pic\')) {
$blacklist = array('.', '..', 'bu');
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
  if (!in_array($file, $blacklist)) {
    echo "<iframe width='800' height='600' src='http://www.url.com/run_batch.php?q=" . "$file" . "'></iframe>";
        sleep(100);
    }
}
closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a sleep in PHP code, the HTML is not sent to the browser, that is why it looks busy.

You have to call flush() on each pass.

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('D:\HTTP\pic\')) {
$blacklist = array('.', '..', 'bu');
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
  if (!in_array($file, $blacklist)) {
    echo "<iframe width='800' height='600' src='http://www.url.com/run_batch.php?q=" . "$file" . "'></iframe>";
        //Send content to browser
        flush();
        sleep(100);
    }
}
closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I can see it now, but its opening a new iframe for every item in the array, which makes sense when reading how I have the code.  How would I make it so that the same iframe is used for each one...?

Comment: so you'll have to modify your conception. PHP sends content all at a time, but you want php to refresh your page automatically. It's not possible. I think your html needs to call php script via javascript, and query the next directory.

If I look closely at your code, you want tu run batches periodically, does batches has to be presented in the browser ? why do you need sleep between batches ? 
If you ask yourself the appropriate questions, you'll find the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start with pseudo code; create comments for the steps.  From there, look at PHP.net for help with specific tasks.  When you have something workable but buggy, paste your code.

**Pseudocode:**

```
// get directory list
// loop through directories
// ...
// redirect to next page
```